# How to add dependency in gradle after evaluate

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I need to dynamically add dependency in gradle when specific dependency exist.

I use this to check if specific dependency exist

```
def hasSb2 = false
def sb2InModule = false
def sbInModule = false

allprojects {
    project ->
        afterEvaluate {
            if (project.name == "XXX") {
                def dependency = project.configurations.getByName("compile").allDependencies.find { c -> c.group == "org.springframework.boot" }
                if (null != dependency) {
                    sbInModule = true
                    if (dependency.version.startsWith("1")) {
                        println(dependency.version)
                        println(project.name)
                        sb2InModule = true
                    }
                }
            }
            project.subprojects.each {
                sp ->
                    if (sp.name== "XXX") {
                        def dependency = sp.configurations.getByName("compile").allDependencies.find { c -> c.group == "org.springframework.boot" }
                        if (null != dependency && dependency.version.startsWith("1")) {
                            println(dependency.version)
                            println(sp.name)
                            hasSb2 = true
                        }
                    }

            }
        }
}
```

I use the following script to change dependency

```
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        project ->
            if (project.name == "XXX") {
                if (sb2InModule || (!sbInModule && hasSb2)) {
                    println("ready to insert")
                    println(project.buildscript.configurations.getByName("classpath").allDependencies)

                    project.buildscript.getDependencies().add("classpath","org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.6.RELEASE")
                    println(project.buildscript.configurations.getByName("classpath").allDependencies)

                }
            }
    }
}
```

but i get the exception

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':XXX'.
> Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':XXX:classpath' after it has been resolved.
```

So I want to know how can I add dependency in init.gradle after evaluate